# How can I use a .zip build file and create a release asset with a GitHub action?

Tags: wordpress, github, github-actions

I am having issues wrapping my head around GitHub actions. I currently use WPack.io to build and create a distributable .zip archive of my WordPress theme. I want to be able to take this .zip and have it at the top level as a release asset upon creating a release in GitHub.  Currently if I locally run the build and archive commands, it will create a .zip of my theme in the /builds directory.  I understand I can use these commands in GitHub actions upon a release, however I am stuck with the part where I would be able to move /builds/theme.zip up to the top level.  Here is what I have so far.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Run WPack Build
        run: |
          npm run build
          
      - name: Run WPack Archive
        run: |
          npm run archive

      - name: Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        with:
          files: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}.zip
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: You want to move `builds/theme.zip` to top level directory of workflow machine ?  or the repository top level dir ?

Comment: I want to take the builds/theme.zip and have it be an asset to the release. So you could download the .zip as a top level link of the release. I have seen scripts where people do this but I’m using WPack so it actually builds a .zip inside the theme and I need it to move that zip to its own link in the release.